# Intersecting Universes

Tags: knowledge, crosswords

*The answer to this crossword is a pair of separate but thematically related video games which have or had releases this year.*

[image: Crossword grid]

#### Clues

```
Across
1. Olympic host city where beach volleyball debuted as a sport
8. Sporting sides
13. Not about to nod off
18. Fall on, as responsibility
19. Those on your side
21. Some bucks
22. Spike ___, Shinji Ikari's English voice in "Neon Genesis Evangelion"
23. Parting gesture where only the thumb and pinky are extended
24. The yellow Teletubby
25. Children's novel which becomes a creature it features when the first letter is changed
27. Down Under canine
29. Block crafted from gunpowder and sand, in "Minecraft" (abbr.)
30. Pairs
34. Sing with lips closed
35. Bro's counterpart
36. Certain sundial numeral
37. "... and more of the same", for short
40. Showed up conspicuously
46. Word abbreviated in 37-Across
47. Puzzle inventor Rubik
48. Gandalf actor McKellen
49. 1974 Carl Douglas hit with the lyric "In fact it was a little bit frightening"
55. Sum (up)
58. Hunt in the "Mission: Impossible" films
59. Urges
62. Comfy top-to-toe apparel
63. Pervasiveness
67. Relaxation spot
68. Kick out
71. Visual novel series with first entry "Nine Hours, Nine Persons, Nine Doors"
73. Connoisseur
75. Sochi's country
77. Imageboard responsible for the popularisation of "rickrolling"
78. "It's not a ___, it's a feature"
81. '80s arcade game featuring an orange ghost Sue
84. ___ welder
85. Serious crime
87. Requires
88. Minor criticism
89. Garment
95. Cry from Scrooge
96. Nevada gambling city
97. Fish which, in the wild, gets its colour from eating krill and shrimp
101. UK expression of exasperation that sounds like a prayer
108. "The Everlasting Guilty Crown" music group
109. Apple release of 2010
110. Olympic host city where rugby sevens debuted as a sport, informally
111. Fly trap
113. Relaxation spot
114. "Throwback" weekday (abbr.)
115. Kick out
118. Music industry bribery involving a lack of disclosure
121. Responded to a bumper sticker, perhaps
124. Coloured eye parts
126. Subscriber's extension
131. Up to
132. Biblical "Promised Land"
133. Something a regular event might have
134. Outdoes
135. Portmanteau garment for the lower half
136. Select, as a radio button

Down
1. Disease for which many dumped cold water onto themselves to raise awareness in 2014 (abbr.)
2. Commercial wax remover
3. Run for it
4. Grassy expanse
5. "Disney ___" (touring skating shows)
6. Hermione's Patronus
7. Enthusiastic, like cheerleaders
8. 2017 walking simulator game by the creators of "Gone Home"
9. Enthusiasm
10. Completely
11. Curry orderer's specification
12. Late tournament match
13. Spanish house
14. ___Vista (defunct service acquired by Yahoo!)
15. Discarded what another player was waiting for, in mahjong
16. Health food buzzword
17. Declaration after throwing scissors against scissors, say
20. Equilibrioception, e.g.
24. Album track for Evanescence ("Evanescence", 2011) or Rihanna ("Unapologetic", 2012)
26. Violet Beauregarde's fixation
28. Vermouth's partner in a martini
30. With 32-Down, "Why do computer programmers confuse Christmas with Halloween? Because ___ 25 = ___ 31."
31. Small truck type, in Australia
32. See 30-Down
33. Look for
36. Vincent ___ Gogh
38. Adjust for evenness, in carpentry
39. "I don't feel like doing it"
41. Alphabet run at the top-right of a keypad
42. Kitamura who voiced Miki Sayaka in "Puella Magi Madoka Magica"
43. "Brokeback Mountain" director Lee
44. Classic Japanese theatre
45. Apt transdeletion for ANGER
50. Alphabet run at the centre-left of a keypad
51. Online help section (abbr.)
52. E pluribus ___ (United States motto)
53. "___ the season ..."
54. Little devil
55. "Wait ___!" ("Not so fast!")
56. Runner in a nursery rhyme
57. Kick-less coffee option
60. ___ Angeles
61. Literary sibling with Lucy, Edmund and Peter
64. Words before or after Sam in "Green Eggs and Ham"
65. Idiot boxes (abbr.)
66. "Uh-huh"
69. Apple release of 2011
70. Social delicacy
72. Suffix for a single-bonded hydrocarbon
74. Inverse of giga-
76. Free after getting caught
79. A, in France
80. Battling venue, in the Pokémon games
82. ___ homme ("this man", in French)
83. Word of indifference
86. Hemsworth who portrayed Gale in "The Hunger Games"
90. Bobby in the Hockey Hall of Fame
91. Payment for a service
92. "Anderson Cooper 360°" broadcaster
93. Keep a record of
94. Gooey lump
95. First B in B&B
98. "Mamma ___!"
99. Collection of music recorded for a game, say (abbr.)
100. Non-specific ordinal
101. Home to many open source projects
102. Apple release of 2007
103. Boasts about excessively
104. Number of balls in an over, in cricket
105. Something to discuss
106. Doubly contracted word
107. "___ Diddle Diddle" (nursery rhyme)
112. Beet soup (var.)
116. Notable periods
117. "Good Mythical Morning" host with Rhett
118. Patridge's tree type in song
119. Fry's mate in "Futurama"
120. Funny business
122. First aid ___
123. Right-angled letters
125. ___ Paulo
127. Engrave, perhaps
128. Collaborative type of site
129. Uncontrolled way to run
130. Fallon's predecessor on US late-night
```

#### Across TEXT (for use with [Across Lite](http://www.litsoft.com/across/alite/download/))

```
<ACROSS PUZZLE V2>
<TITLE>
Intersecting Universes
<AUTHOR>
Sp3000
<COPYRIGHT>
2018
<SIZE>
21x21
<GRID>
XXXXXXX.XXXXX...XXXXX
XXXXXXX.XXXXXX..XXXXX
XXXXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX
....XXXXXX.XXXXX..XXX
XXXX..XXX....XXX.XXXX
XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXX...XXXX..XXX...
...XXXXXXXXXXXXXX....
XXX.XXXXX....XXXXXX..
XXX.XXXXXXXX.XXX.XXXX
XXXXXX..XXXXX..XXXXXX
XXXX.XXX.XXXXXXXX.XXX
..XXXXXX....XXXXX.XXX
....XXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
...XXX..XXXX...XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXX
XXXX.XXX....XXX..XXXX
XXX..XXXXX.XXXXXX....
XXXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXXX
XXXXX..XXXXXX.XXXXXXX
XXXXX...XXXXX.XXXXXXX
<ACROSS>
Olympic host city where beach volleyball debuted as a sport
Sporting sides
Not about to nod off
Fall on, as responsibility
Those on your side
Some bucks
Spike ___, Shinji Ikari's English voice in "Neon Genesis Evangelion"
Parting gesture where only the thumb and pinky are extended
The yellow Teletubby
Children's novel which becomes a creature it features when the first letter is changed
Down Under canine
Block crafted from gunpowder and sand, in "Minecraft" (abbr.)
Pairs
Sing with lips closed
Bro's counterpart
Certain sundial numeral
"... and more of the same", for short
Showed up conspicuously
Word abbreviated in 37-Across
Puzzle inventor Rubik
Gandalf actor McKellen
1974 Carl Douglas hit with the lyric "In fact it was a little bit frightening"
Sum (up)
Hunt in the "Mission: Impossible" films
Urges
Comfy top-to-toe apparel
Pervasiveness
Relaxation spot
Kick out
Visual novel series with first entry "Nine Hours, Nine Persons, Nine Doors"
Connoisseur
Sochi's country
Imageboard responsible for the popularisation of "rickrolling"
"It's not a ___, it's a feature"
'80s arcade game featuring an orange ghost Sue
___ welder
Serious crime
Requires
Minor criticism
Garment
Cry from Scrooge
Nevada gambling city
Fish which, in the wild, gets its colour from eating krill and shrimp
UK expression of exasperation that sounds like a prayer
"The Everlasting Guilty Crown" music group
Apple release of 2010
Olympic host city where rugby sevens debuted as a sport, informally
Fly trap
Relaxation spot
"Throwback" weekday (abbr.)
Kick out
Music industry bribery involving a lack of disclosure
Responded to a bumper sticker, perhaps
Coloured eye parts
Subscriber's extension
Up to
Biblical "Promised Land"
Something a regular event might have
Outdoes
Portmanteau garment for the lower half
Select, as a radio button
<DOWN>
Disease for which many dumped cold water onto themselves to raise awareness in 2014 (abbr.)
Commercial wax remover
Run for it
Grassy expanse
"Disney ___" (touring skating shows)
Hermione's Patronus
Enthusiastic, like cheerleaders
2017 walking simulator game by the creators of "Gone Home"
Enthusiasm
Completely
Curry orderer's specification
Late tournament match
Spanish house
___Vista (defunct service acquired by Yahoo!)
Discarded what another player was waiting for, in mahjong
Health food buzzword
Declaration after throwing scissors against scissors, say
Equilibrioception, e.g.
Album track for Evanescence ("Evanescence", 2011) or Rihanna ("Unapologetic", 2012)
Violet Beauregarde's fixation
Vermouth's partner in a martini
With 32-Down, "Why do computer programmers confuse Christmas with Halloween? Because ___ 25 = ___ 31."
Small truck type, in Australia
See 30-Down
Look for
Vincent ___ Gogh
Adjust for evenness, in carpentry
"I don't feel like doing it"
Alphabet run at the top-right of a keypad
Kitamura who voiced Miki Sayaka in "Puella Magi Madoka Magica"
"Brokeback Mountain" director Lee
Classic Japanese theatre
Apt transdeletion for ANGER
Alphabet run at the centre-left of a keypad
Online help section (abbr.)
E pluribus ___ (United States motto)
"___ the season ..."
Little devil
"Wait ___!" ("Not so fast!")
Runner in a nursery rhyme
Kick-less coffee option
___ Angeles
Literary sibling with Lucy, Edmund and Peter
Words before or after Sam in "Green Eggs and Ham"
Idiot boxes (abbr.)
"Uh-huh"
Apple release of 2011
Social delicacy
Suffix for a single-bonded hydrocarbon
Inverse of giga-
Free after getting caught
A, in France
Battling venue, in the Pokemon games
___ homme ("this man", in French)
Word of indifference
Hemsworth who portrayed Gale in "The Hunger Games"
Bobby in the Hockey Hall of Fame
Payment for a service
"Anderson Cooper 360" broadcaster
Keep a record of
Gooey lump
First B in B&B
"Mamma ___!"
Collection of music recorded for a game, say (abbr.)
Non-specific ordinal
Home to many open source projects
Apple release of 2007
Boasts about excessively
Number of balls in an over, in cricket
Something to discuss
Doubly contracted word
"___ Diddle Diddle" (nursery rhyme)
Beet soup (var.)
Notable periods
"Good Mythical Morning" host with Rhett
Patridge's tree type in song
Fry's mate in "Futurama"
Funny business
First aid ___
Right-angled letters
___ Paulo
Engrave, perhaps
Collaborative type of site
Uncontrolled way to run
Fallon's predecessor on US late-night
<NOTEPAD>
The answer to this crossword is a pair of separate but thematically related video games which have or had releases this year (2018).
```

---

<sup>*Constructor's note: One entry is also the name of an anime whose opening song would make a very fitting theme entry. However, to avoid solvers running into spoilers from looking stuff up, this tidbit was left out of this crossword.*</sup>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution to the crossword is:

> [image]

The first game is given by

> the areas with answers extending outside the grid. These spell out Q-FLOOR, CADOI, 104, and HACHIKO, all areas or landmarks in [The World Ends with You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Ends_with_You)'s setting, a fictionalized version of Shibuya, Tokyo.

The second game is given by

> the longest answers in the grid. These are three-word phrases with enumeration (4, 2, 8): and in fact, [428](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/428:_Shibuya_Scramble) is a game *also* set in Shibuya.